# Haskell: Marshaling by creating algebraic data types from within a C function

Tags: haskell, ffi

Is it possible to do all data marshaling in C, generating algebraic data types directly and pushing them back into Haskell land? I would like to avoid doing twice the work (and data copying) by making an intermediate C API / struct layout, and then having to marshal again in Haskell through the Storable interface.

I'm dealing with a third party data marshaling system from a functional DSL which reproduces an abstract syntax tree by calling a set of C function pointer callbacks to map their internal structure to a user defined type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but more painful. Haskell has better facilities for marshalling, so almost all of the time it is easier to do on the Haskell side.

If you want to call Haskell data constructors from C, you will need to use the FFI `foreign export` of the functions you want to call. Introduction here: https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C

Comment: All non-primitive return values need to be wrapped in StablePtr right? How lightweight are they? It gives the impression that they are just generated indices into a global array of ptrs somewhere.